# Nested Forms Redirect After Destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

Is there a way to redirect back to a parent record when a child record is destroyed?

Example: 
Within the Parents show View, children can be created using nested forms. But when removing a child through 'destroy', can the user be redirect back to the SAME Parent record verses being redirected back to the standard Parent Path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `redirect_to` in your destroy action:

```
# assuming this is a nested resourceful route like: /parents/:parent_id/children/:id
def destroy
  parent = SomeModel.find params[:parent_id]
  child = parent.children.find params[:id]
  child.destroy

  redirect_to :back # will redirect back to the referrer (page from where you came from)
end
```

What that does is essentially: `redirect_to request.referrer` which will take the user to the page they were on when they clicked delete on the child model.

Comment: Spot on! I knew it was something simple. Thanks!